# Concat json_object multiple result lines into one in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Essentially I have a select that takes data from tables and builds a json:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'data' VALUE
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_object(KEY 'code'     VALUE tt.code,
                                             KEY 'name'     VALUE tt.name,
                                             KEY 'location' VALUE
                                             tt.location NULL ON NULL)
                                 RETURNING CLOB),
                   KEY 'header' VALUE
                   JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'vr_code' VALUE 'team1',
                               KEY 'date'    VALUE
                               TO_DATE('2022-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') RETURNING CLOB)
                   RETURNING CLOB) l_json_data
  FROM thetable tt
```

Currently what I get is this structure, in which each group is returned in individual rows, how can I "concat" them so they would be filled into one "data" array object?
Current JSON structure:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "60",
      "name": "michael",
      "location": "canada"
    },
    {
      "code": "60",
      "name": "ken",
      "location": "united states"
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "vr_code": "team1",
    "date": "2022-12-31T00:00:00"
  }
};
{
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "70",
      "name": "jim",
      "location": "united states"
    },
    {
      "code": "70",
      "name": "leslie",
      "location": "mexico"
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "vr_code": "team1",
    "date": "2022-12-31T00:00:00"
  }
}
```

The desired JSON structure:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "60",
      "name": "michael",
      "location": "canada"
    },
    {
      "code": "60",
      "name": "ken",
      "location": "united states"
    },
    {
      "code": "70",
      "name": "jim",
      "location": "united states"
    },
    {
      "code": "70",
      "name": "leslie",
      "location": "mexico"
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "vr_code": "team1",
    "date": "2022-12-31T00:00:00"
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot get your existing structure from the query you have posted as you would need a `GROUP BY` clause and your query does not have one. Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and your query that actually generates your current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query returns multiple rows, your current query would be something like:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'code' VALUE code,
             KEY 'name' VALUE name,
             KEY 'location' VALUE location NULL ON NULL
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         ) FORMAT JSON,
         KEY 'header' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'vr_code' VALUE 'team1',
           KEY 'date' VALUE DATE '2022-12-31'
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) AS l_json_data
FROM   thetable
GROUP BY something
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE thetable(code, name, location, something) AS
SELECT '60', 'michael', 'canada', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '70', 'jim', 'united states', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| L_JSON_DATA |
| --- |
| {"data":[{"code":"60","name":"michael","location":"canada"}],"header":{"vr_code":"team1","date":"2022-12-31T00:00:00"}} |
| {"data":[{"code":"70","name":"jim","location":"united states"}],"header":{"vr_code":"team1","date":"2022-12-31T00:00:00"}} |

You need to change it to return a single row which means you need to remove the `GROUP BY` clause so that it aggregates over the entire result set:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'code' VALUE code,
             KEY 'name' VALUE name,
             KEY 'location' VALUE location NULL ON NULL
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         ) FORMAT JSON,
         KEY 'header' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'vr_code' VALUE 'team1',
           KEY 'date' VALUE DATE '2022-12-31'
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) AS l_json_data
FROM   thetable
```

Which, for the same sample data, outputs:

| L_JSON_DATA |
| --- |
| {"data":[{"code":"60","name":"michael","location":"canada"},{"code":"70","name":"jim","location":"united states"}],"header":{"vr_code":"team1","date":"2022-12-31T00:00:00"}} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pg92Smqj)

Comment: @Euridice01 You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [MRE] relevant to your problem.